# React Native - How can I create a dynamic dotted line (leader) between two words?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a component in React Native that simply displays a list of information like so:

```
Device: Macbook
Port: 8080
OS: Darwin
```

However, I'd like to display the text like this:

```
Device.........Macbook
Port..............8080
OS..............Darwin
```

Given the dimensions of most phone screens may be different, how can I achieve this dotted line in such a way that it **dynamically conforms to the phone's dimensions** and looks nice / does not spill over to the next line within the `<View>` / `flexbox`?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding *borderRadius*.

```
<View style={{
    borderStyle: 'dotted',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 1,
  }}>
</View>
```